# Comparing button graphics to Images

Tags: java, arrays, image, javafx, conditional-statements

I have a 2D array of buttons called arr. For my game's win condition, I want to compare the graphics of the buttons to a 2D array of WritableImage's called newImage, where the condition is met once each button graphic is equal to the corresponding image. e.g. arr[0][0] equals newImage[0][0] etc. The code below doesn't seem to compare them, as nothing happens, guessing because of the different objects. Could anyone give any suggestions on how I should tackle this?

```
    if (arr[3][3].getText().equals("blank")) {
        System.out.println("this runs");
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                if (Objects.equals(arr[i][j].getGraphic(), newImage[i][j])) { //If the each button contains the correct corresponding graphic, puzzle is complete
                    System.out.println(arr[i][j] + " is correct");
                }
                setWin = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you have an `if` statement looking at `arr[3][3]`? what is significant about that array element?

Comment: The buttons were puzzle pieces in a slide puzzle. arr[3][3] represented the blank piece which I identified by setting it's text to "blank". I just used the statement so that the win condition is only checked when the blank piece is at the bottom right of the puzzle to avoid unnecessarily running the rest of the procedure.

Comment: The `graphic` property holds a `Node` which, in this case, I suppose will actually be an `ImageView`. In other words, you're testing if an `ImageView` is equal to a `WritableImage` which will never be true. You could try `if (((ImageView) arr[i][j].getGraphic()).getImage() == newImage[i][j])`, assuming you use the exact `WritableImage` instances in the graphics.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend not comparing `Image`s btw: Store the info in a way that allows you to do the check without requiring to compare images, e.g. assign each image an index from 0 to n; storing the index for the image in each button the check would come down to comparing the indices which would work regardless of how many instances of `Image` are in use for each piece...

Comment: You are solving this the wrong way. Your model should be a representation of the puzzle and the UI should render that model. The model should now have "ImageViews"  or "WritableImages". The model then checks if a puzzle is correct, which is depending on the type of puzzle.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys, I'll try some alternatives you recommended :)

Comment: all the discussion help to clear out, how to handle such problems - i'll upvote so others can learn from that thread!